# Simple to enter Unicode character that would sort after Z in most cases?

Tags: sorting, unicode

As you probably know most symbols are sorted before the alphabetical letters.

I am looking for one character that is easy to enter from the keyboard that would be sorted after "z" by most sort implementations.

If this is also an ASCII character, the better :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Z or z, and using what collating sequence?  Just in terms of bit value the character `{` comes after z and the character `[` comes after Z.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes if you're adding to an alphabetised list, and need something to appear at the end, it can be useful to prepend it with a character forcing it to be there, much the same as using a ! can be used to place that item at the beginning of a list

Comment: What do you mean by "the" keyboard?  There are many layouts, and many input methods; the OS and locale can make a big difference.  Also, which language?  In C, `L"\uFFFF"` *might* be a good answer, but the question is really far too broad.

Comment: note that sorting order depends on the locale being used, so a lot of comments below saying that "it doesn't sort after Z in Windows" doesn't make sense, because there are also tons of locales on Windows just like Linux

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On a Mac, these are the only characters I can type using a US keyboard (with and without shift and option modifiers) that sort below Z and z:

- Ω (option+z)
- π (option+p)
- µ (option+m)
-  (shift+option+k)

It seems like omega and then pi are the best options for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Only `π` and `Ω` sort below `Z` on Windows. If you want something smaller, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31072710/482115

Comment: `Ω` worked for me (in C#) but `~` didn't. also `Ω` means 'last' in my head

Comment: `π` and `Ω` Worked nicely for me in outlook for sorting additional folders from the default ones

Comment: `Ω` (omega) is convenient on Mac, because it's easy to recall (option-**z**, and because of the expression "the alpha and omega".)

Answer (score 26):

A Tilde '~' is ASCII code 126.

This comes after all the standard English usage characters and would therefore out-sort a 'Z' of any case.

It would not out-sort other special characters, however ASCII or unicode sequencing is not sufficient to cover international sorts in any context.

[Example: internationisation in javascript](http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/10/alphabetical-sort-in-javascript-and-indesign)

Comment: Exactly what the OP asked for - a character than can easily be entered from the keyboard that sorts after 'Z'

Comment: Sorts after Z according to which algorithm? Not all sorts are by ordinal value. Example: https://ideone.com/1b4iP8. A character that in one particular case sorts after "Z" is far from one that is sorted after "z" in most implementations.

Comment: It's sorted before the letters in Windows Explorer

Comment: This one works great for a report name in a Power BI workspace.

Comment: ~ worked for me in the program I needed that kind of sorting

Comment: Looks like even though `~`, `{`, `|`, and `}` are all after `z` in ASCII order, most things still sort them all before alphabetic characters, for some reason. For instance, sorting in Gmail. `Ω` works best there - but I hate using a non-base character that might show up different somewhere else, but don't really have any other option unless I want to do `zzz` which looks more obnoxious.

Answer (score 25):

On Windows, none of these options work because they all sort before `A`.

A solution I ended up using is an Arabic character:

> ٴ  This folder comes after `z` in windows

[Source](http://forums.massassi.net/vb3/showthread.php?42027-Windows-Sort-files-by-name-What-character-will-come-after-Z-in-the-list&s=6274c6aa95bfd8c8593176ddb2578d34&p=698132&viewfull=1#post698132)

Comment: Now that's funny ! I couldn't see the character on your answer nor in the source. But anyway, I copied what looks like two spaces in the last message from your source, and when pasted as a folder name, the arabic character appeared and the folder was sorted after "z" as expected.

Comment: Not sure if it's poor form to reply after a few years, but this really helped me out.  I should have thought of it myself, as I do a lot of Arabic typing for school.

Comment: @Ernesto not at all, glad it helped :)

Comment: @degenerate In Windows, it looks like any language character will work, starting with Greek and onward, but anything that serves as a symbol or punctuation or phonetics, even in those ranges, will not work. (I should add that I checked this in Excel, not for Windows generally.) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot: it works on MacOS too, though while on Windows the ٴ character displays at the start of the filename, on MacOS in Finder it ends up behind the extension (as Arabic script is right-to-left) and is very hard to remove. On the MacOS Terminal it ends up on the left and is easy to modify.

Comment: Having trouble copying this from your answer for some reason. To be explicit, here's the symbol: "ٴ" ... My system acts funny when trying to work with this character. Copy, Paste, then Typing was causing some weird side effects. Nonetheless, it works for sorting.

Answer (score 22):

**Xi "`Ξ`" works nicely!**

On Mac: Ctrl+Cmd+Space, then type "xi".

Comment: This is by far the most aesthetically pleasing option. Thank you.

Comment: and it works in google drive as well as macOS. While ~ unfortunately sorts in front of letters I google drive. Thank you

Comment: ΞSo aesthetically pleasing!

Answer (score 13):

The answers provided here that worked for me:

- Ξ _Greek capital letter XI (per tonystar's answer);
- π _Greek small letter PI (per DaveC's answer);
- Ω _Greek capital letter OMEGA (per DaveC's answer);
- µ _international symbol for micrometre, previously and AKA micron (per DaveC's answer);
- ٴ  _Arabic letter ٴ(unidentified) (per degenerate's answer);
- ﻩ _Arabic letter HEH isolated form (per Bytee's answer);

*Notes:*

- using macOS 10.14.2.
- a tilde ~ always displays before numbers in an ascending sort.

---

In macOS Numbers (spreadsheet) app, sort (ascending) displays as follows:

- 0
- 9
- a
- z
- µ
- Ξ
- π
- Ω
- ٴ
- ﻩ

Perhaps worth mentioning that the last two Arabic letters ٴ    (unknown) and ﻩ (HEH) are difficult to edit (not as expected) in Numbers.

---

In macOS Finder, sort (ascending) displays as follows:

- ٴ  (appears as a narrow 'blank' space at the beginning of the file name)
- 0
- 9
- a
- z
- µ
- Ξ
- π
- Ω
- ﻩ (appears at the end of the file name in display, at the beginning during edit)

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I was tearing my hair out to find a character that sorted last that wouldn't tweak my OCD either. Finally found this Arabic character "ﻩ" sorts after z. Putting one on either side of the folder name like so...
ﻩ Odds & Ends ﻩ 
...looks rather pretty to me, so maybe it'll work for you all too!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it somehow invisible you can use no-break-space ascii code:

Windows: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (only works with numpad)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Excel for Windows (Excel 2013 specifically). Maybe Excel uses a different algorithm that identifies more character codes as throwaways than Windows generally.

Comment: @vknowles Yes not all applications regard ASCII sort order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do this to my Amazon Wishlists. None of the suggestions here have worked (I have tried, `Ω`, `Ξ`, `~`).

I ended up using `zzz_`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a sort with `LC_ALL=C` sorts by ascii value, so `{|}~` and `DEL` will come after z.

```
% echo $'a\nA\n1\n@\n~' | LC_ALL=C sort
1
@
A
a
~
```

It appears this is default when LC_ALL is not set on mac/bsd sort but must be explicitly set for gnu sort.

Answer (score 0):

What I like using for this purpose is Greek letters and some similar symbols from [Greek and Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic) Unicode block. I have a note with all these symbols and copypaste from it, but I'm sure there are better ways of entering them. This is my current list in sorted order. They all sort after `z` on Windows US locale. Yes, even `Α` goes after `z`.

```
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϘϙϞϟϪϫϵ϶ϽϾ
```